# is devexpress 13.1 is compatible to windows 7?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I created an application from vb.net with devexpress controls like ribboncontrol from windows 8.1, and when i try it to run on windows 7 it does not work. is there something wrong on windows compatibility on devexpress or something it needs an requirements so that devexpress or windows .exe from vb.net can also run on windows 7.

Comment: Maybe you're using older version of .NET Framework on Win7?

Comment: You may get better results if you ask the fine people at devexpress.

Comment: my vb.net is 2013. and my OS is windows 8.1 sir nidzaaaa

Comment: maybe sir steven doggart. ill try it

Comment: An error message would be helpful in identifying the issue. I usually find these kind of things are missing dependencies or the latest version of the framework not being installed. I've used 13.x with Win7.

Answer (score 0):

> my vb.net is 2013. and my OS is windows 8.1

You've mentioned that you're using VS2013 at win8.1. I believe the [Target Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) option is set to `4.5` or  even `4.5.1` in your application project (since this is default settings for such configuration).

I far as know the DevExpress controls provides full support of VS2010/VS2012/VS2013 and .Net 4.0+.
Proof: [Shipping Versions & Supported Technologies](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/versions.xml)

So, please check that the same .Net Framework version with which your app has been built is available onto your Win7 machine where this app won't start. Or else rebuild your app with lower version of .Net.